# Replace #1 with something else in the definition of a command

Tags: macros

In the develop version of the package `cleveref-usedon`, there is a command `\SetUsedByAndOnMessageStyle`, currently simply defined as

```
\NewDocumentCommand \SetUsedByAndOnMessageStyle { m }
  {
    \cs_set:Nn \__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn { #1 }
  }
```

so that when user write something like

```
\SetUsedByAndOnMessageStyle
  {%
    \todo{%
      \UsedByAndOnMessageText{#1}{#2}%
    }%
  }
```

the internal command `\__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn` shall be defined as the specified content. However, I would like the users to be able to write

```
\SetUsedByAndOnMessageStyle
  {%
    \todo{%
      #1% <--- Changed line
    }%
  }
```

and let the command `\SetUsedByAndOnMessageStyle` to replace this `#1` with `\UsedByAndOnMessageText{#1}{#2}`. Is this possible? (For example, via some auxiliary macros?)

---

Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% Some preset for testing
\cs_new:Nn \__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn { }
\NewDocumentCommand \UsedByAndOnMessageText { m m }
  {
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item #1
      \item #2
    \end{enumerate}
  }

% This is the command to be improved
\NewDocumentCommand \SetUsedByAndOnMessageStyle { m }
  {
    \cs_set:Nn \__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn { #1 }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \test { m m }
  {
    \__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\SetUsedByAndOnMessageStyle{
  \color{red}
  % \UsedByAndOnMessageText{#1}{#2} % This generates the ideal result
  #1
}

\test{a}{b}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this what you want?

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \SetUsedByAndOnMessageStyle { m }
  {
    \cs_set:Npn \__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn  ##1 { \cs_set:Nn \__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn { #1 } }
    \__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn { \UsedByAndOnMessageText{##1}{##2} } 
  }
\SetUsedByAndOnMessageStyle
  {
    \todo{ #1  }
  }

\cs_show:N \__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn 

\SetUsedByAndOnMessageStyle{
  \color{red}
  % \UsedByAndOnMessageText{#1}{#2} % This generates the ideal result
  #1
}

\cs_show:N \__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn 

\stop
```

console-output:

```
pdflatex test.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
> \__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn=\long macro:#1#2->\todo {\UsedByAndOnMessageText
{#1}{#2}}.
<recently read> }
                 
l.13 \cs_show:N \__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn
                                        
? 
> \__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn=\long macro:#1#2->\color
{red}\UsedByAndOnMessageText {#1}{#2}.
<recently read> }
                 
l.21 \cs_show:N \__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn
                                        
? 
 )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

An attempt at giving some explanation:

It might be confusing at first glimpse, but you can provide hashes (<kbd>#<sub>6</sub></kbd>) as components of macro arguments like any other non-`\outer`-tokens.

What might make things seem subtle at first glimpse is the need of being picky about "hash-doubling" in nested macro-definitions and "hash-collapsing" at the time of expanding macros:

At the time of expanding a macro, some tokens come from the macro's ⟨replacement text⟩ provided at the time of defining the macro. Other tokens come from the arguments of the macro gathered at the time of expanding the macro.

If at the time of defining a macro two consecutive hashes are provided in the ⟨replacement text⟩, then at the time of expanding the macro these two consecutive hashes collapse into a single hash.

If in TeX you define `\def\macro{\string##}`, then expanding `\macro` yields `\string #`.

If in expl3 you define `\cs_new:Npn \macro{\token_to_str:N ##}`, then expanding `\macro` yields `\token_to_str:N #`.

This "collapsing of hashes" is the reason why you can/need to double hashes when nesting definitions inside definitions. But the small definition just provided shows that "collapsing of hashes" is not restricted to nesting definitions inside definitions.

And one needs to be aware that this collapsing of hashes only applies to hashes coming from ⟨replacement text⟩ provided at the time of defining. It does not apply to hashes gathered as components of macro-arguments at the time of expanding the macro.

Via `\SetUsedByAndOnMessageStyle` you wish to provide a macro argument which is to form the ⟨replacement text⟩ for the macro `\__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn`, which in turn takes two arguments.
With that ⟨replacement text⟩-argument you wish `#1` to be replaced by `\UsedByAndOnMessageText{#1}{#2}`.

So the idea is in a first step to define (via `\cs_new:Npn`, where you can specify parameter-text `p` independent from the signature of the name of the macro to be defined) a "scratch-variant" of `\__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn`, which despite the signature `:nn` processes only one argument—the `#1` you provide with `\SetUsedByAndOnMessageStyle`'s "⟨replacement text⟩-argument"—and which redefines itself to process two arguments.

In a second step the scratch-variant is called with `\UsedByAndOnMessageText{#1}{#2}` as its argument, which now makes into the ⟨replacement text⟩ instead of `#1`.

E.g.,

```latex
\SetUsedByAndOnMessageStyle
  {
    \todo{ #1  }
  }
```

with `\SetUsedByAndOnMessageStyle`'s argument `#1` = `\todo{ #1  }`, and taking into account that two consecutive hashes in `\SetUsedByAndOnMessageStyle`'s ⟨replacement text⟩ collapse into a single hash, yields:

```latex
\cs_set:Npn \__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn  #1 { \cs_set:Nn \__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn { \todo{ #1  } } }
\__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn { \UsedByAndOnMessageText{#1}{#2} }
```

, thus  the second line,

```latex
\__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn { \UsedByAndOnMessageText{#1}{#2} }
```

yields

```latex
\cs_set:Nn \__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn { \todo{ \UsedByAndOnMessageText{#1}{#2}  } }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems to work. But how? Would you mind adding some explanation to this new definition? It seems to me that `\__UsedByAndOnMessage:nn` has become something that rewrite itself, but then why can it still be used normally as in `\test`? So amazing!

Comment: @Jinwen I tried to add some explanation, but as English is not my 1st language, this took some time. Sorry for the delay. :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation! It really makes things a lot clearer. I can't thank you enough for the time you have spent on this!

Comment: @Jinwen You are welcome.:-)

Comment: The commands inspired by your code here appear in the package [cleveref-forward](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref-forward), and you may find your name in the Acknowledge section in the README file :-)